# How to use library project in Android Studio?

Tags: android, listview, module, android-studio

I am tyring to use this module or another to make the section headers on my list view stick to the top.

http://applidium.github.io/HeaderListView/

Now in its readMe file it says

```
1. Import the project in Eclipse then add it to the build path of your project.
2. Replace your ListView with HeaderListView
3. Implement a subclass of SectionAdapter
4. Set it to your HeaderListView with setAdapter(SectionAdapter adapter)
```

Now would I import the whole project file into Android Studio to get this working? And would I need to add anything to my gradle file?

And would would I do File > Import Project or Import Module?

Or how to add and use this project from github

https://github.com/vinc3m1/android-segmentedradiobutton

Thanks for the help :)

**EDIT**

I now need help setting up the HeaderView with my list view and data he is how I am currently have my ListView with headers that do not stick. I want it set up so they stick.

here is my data, where the keys are section headers and values are cells.

```
linkedHashMap = {Pizza=[Cheese Pizza - Slice, Pepperoni Pizza, Tomato Bruschetta Flatbread Pizza, Herb 
               Seasoned Breadsticks, Spaghetti Sauce with Tomato Bits], 
       Salad=[Salad Bar Station, Green Pepper & Tomato Salad, Lo Mein Noodle Salad],
       Cold Cereal=[Miscellaneous/Peripherals]
       Dessert=[Carnival Cookies, Sweet Cinnamon Brownies, Oreo Crumble Pudding Cup, 
                 Cherry Jell-O Parfait]}
```

Here is my set up.

```
MyCustomAdapter mAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter();
    for (int i = 0; i < linkedHashMap.size(); i++) {
        Object[] headerArray = linkedHashMap.keySet().toArray();
        String headerString = headerArray[i].toString();
        mAdapter.addSeparatorItem(headerString);
        for (int i2 = 0; i2 < linkedHashMap.get(headerString).size(); i2++) {
            mAdapter.addItem(linkedHashMap.get(headerString).get(i2));
        }
    }
```

And and here is my adapter

```
public class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    ArrayList mData = new ArrayList();
    LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

    private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 0;
    private static final int TYPE_SEPARATOR = 1;
    private static final int TYPE_MAX_COUNT = TYPE_SEPARATOR + 1;

    private TreeSet mSeparatorsSet = new TreeSet();

    public MyCustomAdapter() {
        mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public void addItem(final String item) {
        mData.add(item);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void addSeparatorItem(final String item) {
        mData.add(item);
        // save separator position
        mSeparatorsSet.add(mData.size() - 1);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return mSeparatorsSet.contains(position) ? TYPE_SEPARATOR : TYPE_ITEM;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return TYPE_MAX_COUNT;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return mData.get(position).toString();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder = null;
        int type = getItemViewType(position);
        System.out.println("getView " + position + " " + convertView + " type = " + type);
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            switch (type) {
                case TYPE_ITEM:
                    convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_cell_view, parent, false);
                    holder.textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
                    break;
                case TYPE_SEPARATOR:
                    Context context = DiningItemsActivity.this;
                    convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.header_cell_view, parent, false);
                    holder.textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textSeparator);
                    convertView.setBackgroundColor(colorBar);
                    break;
            }
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.textView.setText(mData.get(position).toString());
        return convertView;
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        public TextView textView;
    }


}
```

Comment: Maybe, you can first create a project in Eclipse and then import it in Android Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The library has a demo and I recommend you take a look at that, it is all you have done in your code but in a nice way, for example the library has separated getting header views and row views or number of row views or header views. I think the method name is self-explanatory so just give it a try:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    HeaderListView mHeaderListView;
    LinkedHashMap<String, String[]> mLinkedHashMap;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  

        mHeaderListView = (HeaderListView)findViewById(R.id.HeaderListView_MainActivity);
        mLinkedHashMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        mLinkedHashMap.put("Pizza", new String[]{"Cheese Pizza - Slice","Pepperoni Pizza","Tomato Bruschetta Flatbread Pizza",
                "Herb Seasoned Breadsticks","Spaghetti Sauce with Tomato Bits"});

        mLinkedHashMap.put("Salad", new String[]{"Salad Bar","Green Pepper & Tomato Salad","Lo Mein Noodle Salad"});

        mLinkedHashMap.put("Cold Cereal", new String[]{"Miscellaneous/Peripherals"});

        mLinkedHashMap.put("Dessert", new String[]{"Carnival Cookies","Sweet Cinnamon Brownies","Oreo Crumble Pudding Cup", 
        "Cherry Jell-O Parfait"});


        mHeaderListView.setAdapter(new SectionAdapter() {


            @Override
            public int numberOfSections() {

                return mLinkedHashMap.keySet().toArray().length;
            }

            @Override
            public int numberOfRows(int section) {

                if(section >=0){
                    String sectionKey = (String)mLinkedHashMap.keySet().toArray()[section];
                    int numOfRows = mLinkedHashMap.get(sectionKey).length;
                    return numOfRows;
                }else{
                    return 0;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public boolean hasSectionHeaderView(int section) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public View getRowView(int section, int row, View convertView,
                    ViewGroup parent) {

                ViewHolder holder = null;
                if (convertView == null) {
                    holder = new ViewHolder();
                    LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
                    convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_cell_view, parent, false);
                    holder.textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
                    convertView.setTag(holder);
                } else {
                    holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
                }
                String sectionKey = (String)mLinkedHashMap.keySet().toArray()[section];
                holder.textView.setText(mLinkedHashMap.get(sectionKey)[row]);
                return convertView;

            }

            @Override
            public Object getRowItem(int section, int row) {

                return ((String[])mLinkedHashMap.keySet().toArray()[section])[row];
            }

            @Override
            public View getSectionHeaderView(int section, View convertView,
                    ViewGroup parent) {
                ViewHolder holder = null;
                LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
                if (convertView == null) {
                    holder = new ViewHolder();          
                    convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.header_cell_view, parent, false);
                    holder.textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textSeparator);
                    convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));


                    convertView.setTag(holder);
                } else {
                    holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
                }
                holder.textView.setText((String)(mLinkedHashMap.keySet().toArray()[section]));

                return convertView;
            }
        });


    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView textView;
    }

}
```

item_cell_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="12sp"  
        />


</LinearLayout>
```

header_cell_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/textSeparator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="12sp"  
        />


</LinearLayout>
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <com.example.your package name of HeaderListView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/HeaderListView_MainActivity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#eff4ee"
        android:divider="#000000"
        android:dividerHeight="2dp"
        android:padding="8dp" />
```

Comment: right so in the example this is all being done in `onCreate` but I am getting data from the web and doing a lot of this setup in `MyCustomAdapter` is it all the same can I put this code in there?

Comment: you can create an adapter that extends `SectionAdapter` with a constructor that receives `mLinkedHashMap` then whenever your data is ready create the adapter and pass the `mLinkedHashMap` and set it for the `mHeaderListView`, this is just an example that I want to show you how you can use that library with your data.

Comment: I am getting a compile error `error: package com.applidium.headerlistview does not exist` ? and `error: cannot find symbol class headerlistview`

Comment: I have not added the library completely to my project I just added the source codes so go to this [Link](https://github.com/applidium/HeaderListView/tree/master/HeaderListView/src/main/java/com/applidium/headerlistview) and download those files then add those files to your src folder of your mainactivity (also change the package name of those files to match the pakage name of your main activity)and also add [images](https://github.com/applidium/HeaderListView/tree/master/HeaderListView/src/main/res/drawable) to your drawable folder.

Comment: hey I got the header view working any help on the `segmented radio button`

Comment: first look at the demo in the library then use it as a sample to add to your project.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67261/discussion-between-iqueqiorio-and-mmlooloo).

Answer (score 0):

For the `HeaderListView` , you can get code [here](https://github.com/applidium/HeaderListView), import the `HeaderListView` folder as Module(import module)

For Second, just clone and import project. It's a sample code.

Comment: Hey man I have imported the HeaderListView and am trying to get it set up are you fimiliar with setting this up I will post a bounty on this for your help :)

Comment: Hi, I tried, it works. You just need to run HeaderListViewDemo, you can see a quick Demo, it's very nice

Comment: For set up, you can read here: https://github.com/applidium/HeaderListView/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Did you see the demo? What kind of code you need to setup, you can post it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67183/discussion-between-iqueqiorio-and-bjiang).